# Angular js files in dist do not have es-2015 suffix causing 404 errors in console

Tags: angular, maven, ecmascript-6, dependencies, package.json

After upgrading from Angular 11 to Angular 13 I see 404 errors on files like 'runtime-es2015.js' in the console when loading the page:

[image]

**Note: the page loads fine for ng serve. but when I use ng build I see those errors in console.**

I am using maven to generate a .war file that contains the compiled angular project code with some custom java files included.

Before these files existing in dist:
[image]

Now I see files with different names in dist:
[image]

my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "DEXAngularDashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --base-href",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.2",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.0.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "async-wait-until": "^2.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "bpmn-js": "^9.0.3",
    "camunda-bpmn-moddle": "^6.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^9.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.2.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "oauth2-oidc": "^0.1.38",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^13.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.3.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~17.0.23",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.7.0",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3"
  }
}
```

my angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "48b684d7-bae5-408a-b798-897ccb3a6b16"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "DEXAngularDashboard": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",

              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
               "optimization": false,
               "sourceMap": true,
               "namedChunks": true,
               "extractLicenses": false,
               "vendorChunk": true,
               "buildOptimizer": false
            },                 
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true,
                "fonts": false   
              }, 
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "DEXAngularDashboard:build:production"                                                         
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "DEXAngularDashboard:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"                                   
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DEXAngularDashboard:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "DEXAngularDashboard:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "DEXAngularDashboard:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "DEXAngularDashboard"
}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<project>
    ....
   <build>
        <finalName>${project.name.output}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            .....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>

                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${DEXAngularDashboard.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>install-node-and-npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v16.10.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>7.5.6</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install --legacy-peer-deps</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install --legacy-peer-deps</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
               
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                     <!-- Note: edit "build" in package.json in section 'scripts' to change these arguments -->
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${release.project.directory}/apps</outputDirectory>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${DEXAngularDashboard.project.location}/dist</directory>
                            <targetPath>/WEB-INF/resources/angularFiles</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` seems to be missing angular's post install script

Add this to your "scripts" block in `package.json` (this entry is created by default in new angular apps)

```
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
```

Then every time you run `npm install` [pre-compiled entries](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#N) will get created into the node_modules folder

I also recommend you to:

- delete your node_modules folder and recreate it with `npm install`
- create a brand new angular app on v13 and make sure to port new configurations you find in it to your app. Sometime the upgrade script misses configs